# Creating a dynamic query

Tags: django

Please tell me how to make this query dynamic:

```
products = category.product_set.filter(Q(feature__value__value='Red')
|Q(feature__value__value='Blue'), feature__name__name='Color')
```

I need to show all the products with the color red and blue.

And tell me please how best to do this query:

All products with a red and blue, but with Option-1. I understand that right?:

```
products = category.product_set.filter(Q(feature__value__value='Red')
|Q(feature__value__value='Blue'), feature__name__name='Color').filter(Q(feature__value__value='Yes')
|Q(feature__value__value='No', feature__name__name='Option-1')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
# create a dynamic set of keywords
kwargs = {}
name = 'Color'
# since you're looking for literals, I would simply use 'in' as the query
kwargs[name + "__in"] = ['Red','Blue']

products = category.product_set.filter(**kwargs)
```